# Volley Android Library

Tags: android-volley

I want to update database and get the updated value from the database. Volley uses cache mechanism. I want to change my code such that when database is updated then the data will be fetched from the database server but when the database is not updated then the data will be fetched from the cache. 
In my app the database is updated but the changes is not reflected in my app. When i reinstall the app the changes is reflected in the app. How to handle the cache mechanism of volley to handle the database updates. Please help me....

Comment: And how would the client side cache know that the database is updated? The best approach would be to always try to get new data, or at least poll if there is a change, and only use the cached version as a fallback. For generated data, you might use a server side cache which can easily be purged from the server if there is a change.

Comment: I don't think Volley is that "Smart". In fact, it doesn't requires to be. How frequent your data set changes ? You can notify clients to fetch new data like Gmail app, etc.

Comment: How to notify client to fetch new data?